# Como usar Token com PHP Rest

Tags: php, web-service, api, rest

Galera, resolvi utilizar o recurso de Token, para acessar meu Rest que estarei fazendo em PHP, principalmente para aprender este conceito, mas não quero usar um Framework pronto, até mesmo preciso pegar o jeito nisso.

Bom pesquisando achei a seguinte solução:
Quando o meu usuario logar no sistema vou gerar um Token e um tempo para esse Token e vou salvar no banco de dados.. Até ai ok.

A cada requisição eu verifico se o Token ainda é válido. A minha dúvida em si seria o seguinte caso.

É algo "legal" usar desta maneira? Sobrecarregaria o meu servidor? Outra coisa, eu preciso que a minha aplicação tenha validação se o usuário esta logado ou não.
Trabalhando com as Sessions do PHP era fácil, se a Sessão existe o cara navega na pagina se não existe vai pro Login.

Mexendo com o Token não vou ter sessão, ai entra a duvida como que ficaria tudo isso? Porque o Token salvaria em LocalStorage no JS e verificaria se existe, e sempre vai existir certo?

Fiquei meio perdido neste item.. Hahaha..

Agradeço a ajuda de vocês!!!

Comment: O Token seria o mesmo que o Session. Se o usuário não possui um Token válido então está desconectado. O mesmo de quando editava o cookie `PHPSESSID` para outro valor qualquer. O fato de sobrecarregar ou não eu acredito que não. O Session le e edita um arquivo, geralmente na pasta temporária. Enquanto o token irá verificar isto no banco de dados. Para mim o Session possui só possui maleficio de performance, já que não pode ser lido/alterado por dois processos simultâneos. Já usando o token na DB (supondo MySQL) você pode usar o `InnoDB` com `READ UNCOMMITTED`, dessa forma não terá esse problema